# Stop Intellij IDEA from completing </ HTML tag

Tags: html, jsp, intellij-idea

Just switched to this ide and so far it's been mostly a pain. If I try to create a closing tag it autocompletes it. How do I stop this? It keeps putting in the wrong tags since I'm not closing tags within the div.

```
<div>
    <form:input path="foo"/>
</
```

If I type the above, it will complete to form:input not div. I cannot begin to describe how irritating this is, and I cannot find the option to disable it. Help! Please!

Comment: What version of IntelliJ are you using? Mine (13.1.3) is autocompleting you example with a `</div>`.

Comment: 13.1.3
I'm using the vim plugin but I don't think that would make any difference.